# How extract only a part of a array key (string) & change its case

Tags: php, arrays, string, algorithm, associative-array

I have an array called `$Bond`:

```
$Bond = array (
    'Sean Connery' => 'Dr. No',
    'George Lazenby' => 'On Her Majesty\'s Secret Service',
    'Roger Moore' => 'Live and Let Die',
    'Timothy Dalton' => 'The Living Daylights',
    'Pierce Brosnan' => 'GoldenEye',
    'Daniel Craig' => 'Casino Royal'
);
```

I need to extract ONLY the last names from the Keys & print them as uppercase.

How in the world would I go about that?

Comment: you can start coding using `foreach`

Comment: If u really have spent hours! then you can share the work to help you out!!

Comment: I know about foreach and how to pull keys, but since the two names make up the entire key I don't know how to pull only the last name.

Comment: @Skitz Have you tried something ? If yes, include your attempts/effort in your question! Show your work! Even if your question is answered, you still improve your post with this and maybe get an upV :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow several ways you can make an array of keys with `array_keys()` and then go through your array of keys with a `for()`, split the name with `explode()` and convert to upper the last name (`end($info)`) with `strtoupper()`. See the code:

```
<?php

    $Bond = array (
    'Sean Connery' => 'Dr. No',
    'George Lazenby' => 'On Her Majesty\'s Secret Service',
    'Roger Moore' => 'Live and Let Die',
    'Timothy Dalton' => 'The Living Daylights',
    'Pierce Brosnan' => 'GoldenEye',
    'Daniel Craig' => 'Casino Royal'
    );

$array_keys = array_keys($Bond);

for($i = 0; $i < count($array_keys); $i++) {
    $info = explode(' ', $array_keys[$i]);
    echo strtoupper(end($info)) . "<br>\n";
}
?>
```

Or you can go to through your array with the `foreach()` split the name with `explode()` and convert to upper the last name (`end($info)`) with `strtoupper()` something like this:

```
<?php

    $Bond = array (
    'Sean Connery' => 'Dr. No',
    'George Lazenby' => 'On Her Majesty\'s Secret Service',
    'Roger Moore' => 'Live and Let Die',
    'Timothy Dalton' => 'The Living Daylights',
    'Pierce Brosnan' => 'GoldenEye',
    'Daniel Craig' => 'Casino Royal'
    );

foreach($Bond as $key => $value) {
    $info = explode(' ', $key);
    echo strtoupper(end($info)) . "<br>\n";
}
?>
```

Output in both cases:

```
CONNERY
LAZENBY
MOORE
DALTON
BROSNAN
CRAIG
```

Comment: Dude it worked! Thank you so much! I could cry right now lol. I used the last option it worked like a charm!

Comment: @Skitz You're welcome, don't cry, just read a little more about arrays in: http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php ;-)

Comment: Thanks man I will. Up until now I've been using W3Schools but I couldn't find anything there to help me this time.

Answer (score 1):

This would loop through each item and give you the last name.

```
foreach($box as $k=>$v){
  $lastName = explode(' ',$k)[1];
  echo strtoupper($lastName);
}
```

This could break if you had someone with a name like "Mary Jo" or "Bobby Jo" as a first name.  In that case you may have to make some changes if this is going to occur.

Edit. I implemented the end function to ensure the last name.

```
foreach($box as $k=>$v){
  $lastName = explode(' ',$k);
  echo strtoupper(end($lastName));
}
```

Comment: you could just use `end()` to get the last exploded element/piece, so that you're guaranteed to get the last name

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Ghost.  I added it to the function above.

Comment: This wasn't working for me for some reason. I was getting an error on the line with the [1]. I got it working from what the last guy on the post said though. Thanks a lot for the help James.

Answer (score 0):

Since the actor names fall on the keys, use foreach, then you could just use `strrchr` + `substr` to get the last name:

```
foreach($Bond as $name => $movie) {
    $last = strtoupper(substr(strrchr($name, ' '), 1));
    echo $last, '<br/>';
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tKvWrr)

Comment: Thanks man I got it. The guy below you code worked for me but I want to remember this way of doing it as well. I never knew of substr or strrchr before. Thanks for the help Ghost.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, nice and compact:

(Here I go through all array keys with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), where I then [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) each key by a space as delimiter. And then access the last element which I return in [`strtoupper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) case)

```
<?php

    $lastNamesUpper = array_map(function($v){
        return strtoupper(explode(" ", $v)[substr_count($v, " ")]);
    }, array_keys($Bond));


    foreach($lastNamesUpper as $v)
        echo "$v<br>";

?>
```

output:

```
CONNERY
LAZENBY
MOORE
DALTON
BROSNAN
CRAIG
```